# How train function in caret choose lamda for elastic net

Tags: r, caret, elastic-net

I'm a beginner in elastic net. I'm using following code for elastic net in R

```
model <- train(
scaleSales_TT ~., data = train_data, method = "glmnet",
trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
tuneLength = 10
)
```

In this setting I'm seeing 10 different alpha value & 10 different lambda value but after changing tunelength=20 I'm seeing 20 different alpha value & 18 different lambda value.I'm seeing that alpha values are equally spaced between 0.1 to 1 & gap between two apha values are determined using tune length. But I'm unable to find how lambda values are being estimated. Can you please help me understand?

Comment: Difficult without working data to see, but the `lambda` part of the grid is separated exponentially; i.e. if you sort the 18 values then each is a constant multiple of the preceding value.  I would guess with `tunelength=20` you saw a warning saying `In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :  There were missing values in resampled performance measures` and this led to you having 18 rather than 20 `lambda` values

Comment: Sorry, I can't able to share the data. Can you let me know how lamdas are generated using train function? I will try to map it with my data set

Comment: You should at least read the help page for `glmnet` (e.g. page 9 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf ) and another question on the [maximum of lambda](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166630/glmnet-compute-maximal-lambda-value)

Comment: tunelength isn't even mentioned in the pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from the function:
caret::getModelInfo("glmnet")

function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
if(search == "grid") {
out <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0, 1, length = len),
lambda = c(0, 10 ^ seq(-1, -4, length = len - 1)))
} else {
out <- data.frame(alpha = runif(len, min = 0, 1),
lambda = 2^runif(len, min = -10, 3))
}
out
}